# Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, webdeploy

When trying to deploy the web application 4.0 on to the server it is giving this error, although its working fine on the local machine having IIS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LoadSuccessExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptresourcedefinition.loadsuccessexpression.aspx) property is a new property in .NET 4.5. Since your host only supports .NET 4, this property does not exist when deployed.

It works on your local machine since .NET 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to .NET 4.  If you install Visual Studio 2012, this property will be found and not give exceptions locally.