# Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've built a fairly simple website in using Visual Studio 2012 using .net 4.5 version.

When I uploaded the website to my server I get the following error:

Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'.

[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'.]
   Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebFormsv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebFormsv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +423
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebFormsv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9090876
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256

(the hosting company provides the following: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272)

I am aware of this question/answer:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1823969.aspx/1 But I find it wasn't very helpful since it doesn't provide any details about where I would correct the references (I am not sure where/what csproj is).

Also I am aware of the similar question posted here with no answers:

[Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038404/method-not-found-void-system-web-ui-scriptresourcedefinition-set-loadsuccessex)

Any tips and suggestions how to fix this issue are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [LoadSuccessExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptresourcedefinition.loadsuccessexpression.aspx) property is a new property in .NET 4.5.  Since your host only supports .NET 4, this property does not exist when deployed.

You're getting a missing method exception since a property setter is really just a method behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi Reed,

Thank you for your quick reply. It's much appreciated. Your explanation certainly clarifies the cause of the error and I thank you for that. Now, I am wondering whether I am out of luck since I am unable to change the .net version from 4.0 to 4.5. It's not an option provided by the hosting company that I am with. Is there anything that I could do to make the error go away?

Thank you!

Comment: @Vasek You'd need to remove that call from your code, and work around it in some other manner.  That functionality just doesn't exist in 4.0

Comment: Thank you Reed for your insight. It's greatly appreciated.