# Method not found: Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web forms project that was started in asp.net 4.5.  I had to drop down to asp.net 4.0 since the host does not support 4.5.  It's been working fine, but now I'm getting the error:

Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'

I'm pretty sure it's because this method does not exist in 4.0, but I'm having trouble chasing down the source of this call.

I'm using nuget package manager and that might be part of the problem if its pulling 4.5 libraries, but just not sure where to find the specific call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: May be these links can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038404/method-not-found-void-system-web-ui-scriptresourcedefinition-set-loadsuccessex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739417/method-not-found-void-system-web-ui-scriptresourcedefinition

Comment: Thanks Aayushi for looking.  I had already figured that much out, I was just having trouble finding the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.  Finally chased down the problem.  I had utility DLL that was using the 4.5 framework.  I moved it down to 4.0, cleaned the solution, rebuilt the solution.

Additionally I had to wipe out files on the web site and FTP the entire project again.  This seemed to be necessary due to the 4.5 reference hanging around somewhere even after the project was downgraded and rebuilt.  I'm guessing it was somewhere in the bin directory, but I decided to start fresh, since this project is not really in "production" yet.