# Method no found exception when deploying my .NET application to production

Tags: .net, missingmethodexception

I created a .NET application originally with .NET 4.5 but then when I realized my server only had 4.0 I reverted the application to 4.0 by going to the property pages option of the project, clicking the build tab and then selecting .NET framework 4.0 as the Target Framework.  Now the app works locally as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038404/method-not-found-void-system-web-ui-scriptresourcedefinition-set-loadsuccessex) post, but on the server it does not. So it seems like there is some aspect of .NET 4.5 that is left over in the project which is being called and is causing the application to crash. The stack trace I am getting is:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'.]
   Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +11802638
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +465
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1167

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjaxv45.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition.set_LoadSuccessExpression(System.String)'..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11791440
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4928277
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I know it's obvious but are you sure you didn't make a silly mistake during upload?

Comment: did you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: Missed a file?  Put them in the wrong dir?  That kind of thing

Comment: OK yeah I think you're actually right thanks!

Comment: Cool, I wrote the above as an answer, feel free to mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake was made during upload.  :)